# Javascript match() function returning full matched tag

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, screen-scraping

```
console.log( html.match( /<a href="(.*?)">[^<]+<\/a>/g ));
```

Instead of returning just the urls like:

```
http://google, http://yahoo.com
```

It's returning the entire tag:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>, <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo.com</a>
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: Because you're using regular expressions to parse html. It's also because the first array item always contains the entire match, and subsequently it has the bracketed matches.

Comment: @Zirak: That's the entire response, but in brackets.

Comment: And I understand the reasons not to use regex for parsing html tags, but this is on nodejs, so I don't have any options. Tried jsdom and apricot, but are riddled with errors and have yet to mature.

Comment: *"but this is on nodejs, so I don't have any options"* You do. :-) You can create your own parsing logic (which may use some targeted regular expressions for bits and pieces), which can be *much* more intelligent for simple extractions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `RegExp#exec` and a loop accessing the element at the match result's `1` index, rather than `String.match`. `String.match` doesn't return the capture groups when there's a `g` flag, just an array of the elements at index `0` of each match, which is the whole matching string. (See Section 15.5.4.10 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).)

So in essence:

```
var re, match, html;

re = /<a href="(.*?)">[^<]+<\/a>/g;
html = 'Testing <a href="http://yahoo.com">one two three</a> <a href="http://google.com">one two three</a> foo';

re.lastIndex = 0; // Work around literal bug in some implementations
for (match = re.exec(html); match; match = re.exec()) {
  display(match[1]);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ejudi4)

But this is parsing HTML with regular expressions. ***Here There Be Dragons.***

---

Update re dragons, here's a quick list of things that will defeat this regexp, off the top of my head:

1. Anything other than exactly one space between the `a` and `href`, such as *two* spaces rather than one, a line break, `class='foo'`, etc., etc.
2. Using single quotes rather than double quotes around the `href` attribute.
3. Not using quotes around the `href` attribute at all.
4. Anything after the `href` attribute that also uses double quotes, e.g.:

   ```
   <a href="http://google.com" class="foo">
   ```

This is not to be down on your regexp, it's just to highlight that regular expressions can't be reliably used *on their own* to parse HTML. They can form part of the solution, helping you scan for tokens, but they can't reliably do the whole job.

Comment: +1 for finding the bug, fixing it *and* detailing everything that is wrong with my regex. I read your comment to the question above too. These links are all that i need in this application, so I think I should be fine as long as I solidify my regex to cover all variations of links, such as the lackings you mentioned. Writing my own parsing logic would really be attempting to reinvent the wheel, specially for something this simple. I am pretty confident jsdom and other parsers out there will mature quite quickly.

Answer (score 3):

While it is true you cannot reliably _*parse*_ HTML using regular expressions, this is not what the OP is asking.

Rather, the OP requires a way to extract anchor links from an HTML document which is easily and admirably handled using regular expressions.

Of the four problems listed by the previous responder:

1. multiple spaces between parts of the anchor
2. using single rather than double quotation marks
3. not using quotation marks at all to delimit the href attribute
4. having other leading or trailing attributes other than href

Only number 3 poses significant problems for a *single* regular expression solution, but also happens to be completely non-standard HTML which should never appear in an HTML document. (Note if you find HTML that contains non-delimited tag properties, there is a regular expression that will match them, but I maintain they aren't worth extracting. YMMV - Your mileage may vary.)

To extract anchor links (hrefs) using regular expressions from HTML, you would use this regular expression (in commented form):

```
<          # a literal '<'
a          # a literal 'a'
[^>]+?     # one or more chars which are not '>' (non-greedy)
href=      # literal 'href='
('|")      # either a single or double-quote captured into group #1
([^\1]+?)  # one or more chars that are not the group #1, captured into group #2
\1         # whatever capture group #1 matched
```

which, without comments, is:

```
<a[^>]+?href=('|")([^\1]+?)\1
```

(Note that we do not need to match anything past the final delimiter, including the rest of the tag, since all we are interested in is the anchor link.)

In JavaScript and assuming 'source' contains the HTML from which you wish to extract anchor links:

```
var source='<a href="double-quote test">\n'+
           '<a href=\'single-quote test\'>\n'+
           '<a class="foo" href="leading prop test">\n'+
           '<a    href="trailing prop test"   class="foo">\n'+
           '<a style="bar" link="baz" '+
                'name="quux" '+
                'href="multiple prop test" class="foo">\n'+
           '<a class="foo"\n href="inline newline test"\n style="bar"\n />';
```

which, when printed to the console, reads as:

```
<a href="double-quote test">
<a href='single-quote test'>
<a class="foo" href="leading prop test">
<a    href="trailing prop test"   class="foo">
<a style="bar" link="baz" name="quux" href="multiple prop test" class="foo">
<a class="foo" 
 href="inline newline test"
 style="bar"
 />
```

you would write the following:

```
var RE=new RegExp(/<a[^>]+?href=('|")([^\1]+?)\1/gi),
    match;

while(match=RE.exec(source)) {
    console.log(match[2]);
}
```

which prints the following lines to the console:

```
double-quote test
single-quote test
leading prop test
trailing prop test
multiple prop test
inline newline test
```

Notes:

1. Code tested in nodejs v0.5.0-pre but should run under any modern JavaScript.
2. Since the regular expression uses capture group #1 to note the leading delimiting quote, the resulting link appears in capture group #2.
3. You might wish to validate the existence, type and length of match using:

   ```
   if(match && typeof match === 'object' && match.length > 1) {
       console.log(match[2]);
   }
   ```

   but it really shouldn't be necessary since RegExp.exec() returns 'null' on failure. Also, note that the correct typeof match is 'object', not 'Array'.